# Flex chart datatip position

Tags: apache-flex, charts

I have created my own dataTipRenderer for a PlotChart and I am trying to change the position at which it is displayed.  I have tried:

```
this.x -= (some number);
this.y -= (some number);
```

Ive tried putting this code in the updateDisplayList function and when I set the data, but that didnt seem to move the datatip at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

need to override the move(x, y) function since this is called externally to set the location after the object's data object is set.

```
override public function move(x:Number, y:Number):void
{
    super.move(x - 17, y - 40);
}
```